# ASP.NET error - PostcodeAnywhere

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now, as part of a large project I have a front-end website for clients to use. Part of this project is a postcode lookup feature, using PostcodeAnywhere which my company is signed up to. Launched it in debugger, tested it, worked perfectly. Launch the website to a dev web server to test it using IIS and BANG!

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{2E01311B-C322-4B0A-BD77-B90CFDC8DCE7}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

That happened upon pressing the button to lookup the postcode. Below is the C# back-end code for the button:

```
    protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    addressparameters.Clear();
    AddressChoice.Clear();
    DataAddressChoice.Items.Clear();
    DataAddressChoice.Items.Add("Please select an address");
    CapturePlus_Interactive_Find("(OMITTED - BUT THE ACCESS CODE IS CORRECT", DataBPostcode.Text, "", "Everything", "GBR", "EN", "7", "100");
    }


    public void CapturePlus_Interactive_Find(string key, string searchterm, string lastid, string searchfor, string country, string languagepreference, string maxsuggestions, string maxresults)
    {
        StringBuilder strurl = new StringBuilder();
        MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP objHttp = new MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP();
        ADODB.Recordset rst = new ADODB.Recordset();
        strurl.Append("http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/CapturePlus/Interactive/Find/v2.10/recordset.ws?");
        strurl.Append("&Key=" + Server.UrlEncode(key));
        strurl.Append("&SearchTerm=" + Server.UrlEncode(searchterm));
        strurl.Append("&LastId=" + Server.UrlEncode(lastid));
        strurl.Append("&SearchFor=" + Server.UrlEncode(searchfor));
        strurl.Append("&Country=" + Server.UrlEncode(country));
        strurl.Append("&LanguagePreference=" + Server.UrlEncode(languagepreference));
        strurl.Append("&MaxSuggestions=" + Server.UrlEncode(maxsuggestions));
        strurl.Append("&MaxResults=" + Server.UrlEncode(maxresults));


        objHttp.open("GET", strurl.ToString(), false, "", "");
        objHttp.send();


        int x = 0;
        rst.Open(objHttp.responseStream);
        while (!rst.EOF)
        {
            AddressChoice.Add(rst.Fields[1].Value);
            splitstring = rst.Fields[1].Value;
            cutoff = splitstring.IndexOf(",");
            splitstring = splitstring.Substring((cutoff + 2), (splitstring.Length - (cutoff + 2)));
            DataAddressChoice.Items.Add(splitstring);
            x++;
            rst.MoveNext();
        }
```

Current online help if thin on the ground here. My prediction is that my dev server is missing a file that VS2013 provides for this sort of thing. Any help you guys can provide would be appreciated!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`, that control is many years old now. Use the XML stuff that is built in to the .Net Framework.

Comment: Also, as you are using Capture+, why do you even need any of this? It's all done in the browser for you by PostcodeAnywhere.

Comment: And while I'm here, don't use `ADODB` too, it's also another legacy technology! :)

Comment: Lack of documentation or explanation on their website means I had to dig around for myself, which ended up with what apparently is a nice little outdated technology :p Although, its taught me a thing or two which means it wasn't all for nought either way

Comment: Learning is good! A few hints for you though. Use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) for HTTP requests and deserialise the response from the web server into your own objects. Much cleaner.